# update/modify nested dict values inside a list

Tags: ansible-2.x

I have a variable which is a list of dictionaries with a nested dictionary, like the following:

```
my_users:
  - { name: "James Doe", user_id: "xman01", user_password: { clear_text: "password1", hash_md5: "", hash_sha512: "" } }
  - { name: "John Dean", user_id: "xman02", user_password: { clear_text: "password2", hash_md5: "", hash_sha512: "" } }
  - { name: "Jane Burn", user_id: "xman03", user_password: { clear_text: "password3", hash_md5: "", hash_sha512: "" } }
  ...
```

During playbook execution I'd like to loop through each item, generate both md5 and sha512 hashes for the clear_text values, and store them back inside the data structure itself, in other words, something like:

```
- name: update users data with password hashes
  set_fact:
    item.user_password.hash_md5 = "{{ item.user_password.clear_text | password_hash('md5') }}"
    item.user_password.hash_sha512 = "{{ item.user_password.clear_text | password_hash('sha512') }}"
  with_items: "{{ my_users }}"
```

I know this does not work in ansible because the syntax is wrong and I've tried to adapt many similar examples I've found out there without any luck.
Any suggestion?

I'm on ansible 2.3.x due to CentOS-5/RHEL-5 compatibility constraints.